# PDI insert for cycle

Tags: php, pdo

I have a form, containing skill name and skill level fields.
This can be dynamically expanded by js so basically they are `skill_name[]` and `skill_level[]`. The point is, that I would like to insert these into the `database`, into separate records.

I have a piece of code, which supposed to do this but not working:

```
$skill_name         = $_POST['skill_name'];
$skill_level        = $_POST['skill_level'];    

for ($is = 0; $is < count($skill_name); $is++) {
        if(!empty($skill_name[$is])) {
            $inserting  = $db->prepare("insert into position_skills 
                (`type`,`pid`,`name`,`general`)
                values 
                ('skill', :pid, :name, :general");
                $inserting  ->execute(
                array(
                ':pid'          => $last_id,
                ':name'         => $skill_name[$is],
                ':general'      => $skill_level[$is]
                )); 
        }
    }
```

The error message is the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]:  Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4' in
>   /home1/xx/public_html/xx/post.php:47 Stack trace: #0
>   /home1/xx/public_html/xx/post.php(47):  PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>   #1 {main} thrown in /home1/xx/public_html/xx/post.php on line 47

```
The line 47 is the end of the arrays.
```

I am totally new to PDO, but other insert is working like a charm. What can be the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Syntax error, thats all. Check the query, you'll find it. StackOverflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: Try to debug or echo out the exact SQL that PDO produces, and run the same query in phpMyAdmin or Sequel Pro or whichever tool you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo... unclosed parentheses.

```
/***/
$inserting  = $db->prepare("insert into position_skills 
               (`type`,`pid`,`name`,`general`)
               values 
               ('skill', :pid, :name, :general)
              ");
```

Comment: And this is why this site has the flag/close reason: `off topic, seeking for debugging help`. Use them. This question is because pure laziness, please keep the noise low by not answering to these. Thanks.